# datastructure help in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am new to OOPS in python. I have create following input file. I written python code to get the details from input file to local class variable. I need help in creating a better way we can arrange and access the input file.

```
DETAILS INPUT   FABRIC -A   FABRIC -A   FABRIC -A   FABRIC-A        FABRIC -B   FABRIC -B   FABRIC -B   FABRIC-B
ARRAY_SERIAL #  T663xt  AB12343                             
HOST_NAME   aaaaa   10000090FA87EC7A    10000090FA87EC7B    10000090FA87EC7C    10000090FA87EC7C    SEPERATION  10000091FA87EC7B    10000091FA87EC7C    10000091FA87EC7D    10000091FA87EC7D
HOST_NAME   bbbbb   10000091FA87ED8A    10000091FA87FC8B    10000091FA87EC8C    10000091FA87EC8D    SEPERATION  10000092FA87ED8E    10000092FA87FC8F    10000092FA87EC8G    10000092FA87EC8H
HOST_NAME   ccccc   10000093FA87ED8D    10000093FA87FC8 10000093FA87EC8C    10000093FA87EC8C    SEPERATION  10000093FA87ED8D    10000093FA87FC8D    10000093FA87EC8C    10000093FA87EC8C
CLUSTER YES                                 
FAB_A_FA    1E:0    2F:0    3G:0                            
FAB_B_FA    16E:0   15F:0   14G:0
```

I have my values in column one and its respective values in next columns.

I have create a calls which has its class variables for all the elements in column 1 like array, hosts (dictionary), cluster, fa_A (dictionary), fa_B (dictionary).

I have storage them in variables so that I can access them to generate some print statements.

For example switch commands functions will generate switch commands for hosts

```
alicreate "aaaaa_hba1", "10000090FA87EC7A"
alicreate "aaaaa_hba2", "10000090FA87EC7B"
alicreate "aaaaa_hba3", "10000090FA87EC7C"
zonecreate "aaaaa_hba1_T663xt_1E_0", "aaaaa_hba1;T663xt_1E_0"
```

and so on I was wondering what would be best way to do this. Will it be better to create class host and instantiate hosts for all the hosts in the input file and generate etc..

please find my code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path
import fileinput
import re

#print "Hello World!!"
class checkingInputFile():
    array   = []    
    host    = {}
    cluster = 0
    fabricAFas = {}
    fabricBFas = {}

    def __init__( self ):
        print "Initializing file class"

    def checkFile ( self, file ):
        self.file = file
        #print ("I am in checkFile "+ file )
        try :
            if os.path.isfile ( self.file ) :
                print ( "File"+ self.file +" exists \n")
            else:
                print "file does not exists"
        except :
            print ( "File " + self.file + "does not exists" )

    def parsingFile ( self, file ):
        self.file   =   file

        print ( "I am in switch command function" + self.file ) 
        for line in fileinput.input ( self.file ):
            #print ( line )     
            arrayTemp = re.search ( r'^ARRAY_SERIAL #,(\w+),(\w+)?,(\w+)?(\w+)?,(\w+)?,.*', line, re.M|re.I ) 
            if arrayTemp is not None :
                #print ("array lenght " + str(len(arrayTemp.group())) )
                count = 0
                try:
                    while arrayTemp.group() is not None:
                        #print arrayTemp.group( count+1 )
                        #print "count value is ", count
                        if arrayTemp.group( count+1 ) is not None :
                        #   print "count value inside if loop ",arrayTemp.group( count+1)
                            checkingInputFile.array.append( arrayTemp.group( count+1 ) )
                            print  " After appending ",checkingInputFile.array
                        count = count + 1
                    else:
                        print " END OF ARRAYS line \n"
                except IndexError:
                    print " No More Array Values"
            ### Creating host Dictionary
            hostTemp = re.search ( r'^HOST_NAME,(\w+)?,?(w+)?,?(\w+)?,?(\w+)?,?(\w+)?,?(\w+)?,?,(\w+),(w+)?,?(\w+)?,?(\w+)?,?(\w+)?,?(\w+)?,', line, re.M|re.I )
            if hostTemp is not None:
                    #print "host values", hostTemp.group()
                    count = 0
                    try:
                        #while hostTemp.group() is not None:
                            #print hostTemp.group( count+1 )
                            #print "count value is ", count
                            if hostTemp.group( count+1 ) is not None :
                            #   print "count value inside if loop ",hostTemp.group( count+1)
                                temp = hostTemp.group().split(",")
                                del temp[0]
                                checkingInputFile.host [ hostTemp.group(count + 1 )] = temp
                                print checkingInputFile.host[hostTemp.group(count + 1 )] 
                            #count = count + 1
                    except IndexError:
                        print " No More Host Values"

            clusterTemp = re.search ( r'^cluster,(\w+),?', line, re.M|re.I )
            if clusterTemp is not None :
                    #print "host values", clusterTemp.group()
                    count = 0
                    try:
                        #while clusterTemp.group() is not None:
                            #print clusterTemp.group( count+1 )
                            #print "count value is ", count
                            if clusterTemp.group( count+1 ) is not None :
                            #   print "count value inside if loop ",clusterTemp.group( count+1)
                                temp = clusterTemp.group().split(",")
                                del temp[0]
                                checkingInputFile.cluster = clusterTemp.group ( count + 1)
                                print checkingInputFile.cluster
                            #count = count + 1
                    except IndexError:
                        print " No More Cluster Values"
            fabricATemp = re.search ( r'^(FAB_A_FA),([\w:]+),?([\w:]+)?,?([\w:]+),?([\w:]+)?,?', line, re.M|re.I )
            if fabricATemp is not None :
                    print fabricATemp.group()
                    count = 0
                    try:
                        #while fabricATemp.group() is not None:
                            #print fabricATemp.group( count+1 )
                            #print "count value is ", count
                            if fabricATemp.group( count ) is not None :
                            #   print "count value inside if loop ",fabricATemp.group( count+1)
                                temp = fabricATemp.group().split(",")
                                del temp[0]
                                checkingInputFile.fabricAFas [ fabricATemp.group(count + 1)] = temp
                                print checkingInputFile.fabricAFas
                            #count = count + 1
                    except IndexError:
                        print " No More Cluster Values"
            fabricBTemp = re.search ( r'^(FAB_B_FA),([\w:]+),?([\w:]+)?,?([\w:]+),?([\w:]+)?,?', line, re.M|re.I )
            if fabricBTemp is not None :
                    print fabricBTemp.group()
                    count = 0
                    try:
                        #while fabricBTemp.group() is not None:
                            #print fabricBTemp.group( count+1 )
                            #print "count value is ", count
                            if fabricBTemp.group( count ) is not None :
                            #   print "count value inside if loop ",fabricBTemp.group( count+1)
                                temp = fabricBTemp.group().split(",")
                                del temp[0]
                                checkingInputFile.fabricBFas [ fabricBTemp.group(count + 1)] = temp
                                print checkingInputFile.fabricBFas
                            #count = count + 1
                    except IndexError:
                        print " No More Cluster Values"
        fileinput.close
class switchCommandGenerator(checkingInputFile) :

    def __init__(self):
        print " I am inside switchCommandGenerator Initilazation"
    #def broacadeCommand (self,*kargs[]):


def main ():
    InputFile = "/home/pradeep/Documents/Scripts/input.csv"
    F1 = checkingInputFile ()
    F1.checkFile( InputFile )

    #SW =   switchCommandGenerator()
    F1.parsingFile ( InputFile )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the no.of records are not huge in 100's of thousands and millions. 
How about just parse and keep the normalized data in memory as below. 
During Implementation, call correspoing item for details.

**Data structure:**

```
serials (list or set)
host (dictionary)
    {
    name: "aaaa"
    Fabric-A: [] (list or set)
    Fabric-B: [] (list or set)
    }
cluster (bool)
fab_A = (dictionary)
fab_B = (dictionary)
```

If it is not going to help ur solution, can you eloborate what exactly u want to build.